# iOSアプリケーション独自で利用可能なOSStatus値域

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOSプログラミングではエラーコードを [`OSStatus`型](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/osstatus?language=objc) で表現しますが、アプリケーション独自のエラーコード定義に使ってよい値の範囲は公式に存在するのでしょうか？コールバック関数からの戻り値などで、システム／フレームワーク定義値と重複しえないエラーコードを定義したいためです。

Web上で検索すると「1000 ～ 9999 がそのような用途に予約済み」という主張も見かけはするのですが、できればApple公式リファレンスなどがあると助かります。

---

追記：本質問の意図は「新規設計する自前ソースコード部で `OSStatus` 型を利用したい」わけではなく、「コールバック関数と組み合わせて用いるレガシーAPIにおいて、コールバック関数が返す `OSStatus`型 の独自エラーコードと、同レガシーAPIが返すエラーコードの衝突が起きない保証を得たい」です。

具体的には [`AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1503098-audioconverterfillcomplexbuffer?language=objc) 関数と、コールバック [`AudioConverterComplexInputDataProc`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audioconvertercomplexinputdataproc?language=objc) において、後者コールバック関数から「アプリケーション独自のエラーコード値」を返して`AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer`呼び出し元に伝搬したいが、フレームワークが定義するエラーコード値との衝突は避けたいです。

Comment: `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer`関数の場合（というよりコールバック関数をとる一般的なAPIでは）任意のユーザデータを渡すことができるので、戻り値ではなくユーザデータで値授受をするのが適切なのかもしれませんね...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple社による古い（2003年頃？）リファレンス "Error Handler Reference" には、下記の記載があったようです（強調部は引用者による）。

> `OSStatus`
>
> A numeric code used in Carbon to indicate the return status of a function.
>
> ```
> typedef SInt32 OSStatus;
> ```
>
> Discussion
>
> The system software sometimes uses error codes to inform an application that a requested service is not possible. Many functions return a result code of type `OSStatus` that indicates whether the function completed successfully, and if not, what the reason for failure was.
>
> If you want to use `OSStatus` to define error codes for your application, **Apple recommends that you use values in the range 1000 through 9999 inclusive.** Values outside of this range are reserved by Apple for internal use.

Answer (score 2):

> iOSプログラミングではエラーコードを OSStatus型 で表現しますが、

ということはなく、正確には標準フレームワークによって提供されている一部の（主に古い）APIで使われている、というのが一般的な理解です。

かつ、 `OSStatus`は単なる数値なので最近のモダンなプログラミングではエラーを返す型としては不十分と一般的に考えられます。

Swiftであるなら、ErrorタイプやSwift 5から入ったResult、Cocoaの文脈ならNSError、や戻り値にエラーを示す専用のデータ構造を作る、など、よりエラーの情報を豊富に返せる方法を選択する方が良いです。

既存のものがそうなっていてそれの改修なら仕方ないですが、通常これから新しく書くiOSプログラミングでOSStatusをエラーとして採用することは合理的ではありません。

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ありません。目的・背景を質問文に追記しました。

Answer (score -1):

`NSException`を使うのはいかがでしょうか？

`MYException.h`

```
extern NSString * _Nonnull const Name1;
extern NSString * _Nonnull const Reason1;
extern NSString * _Nonnull const Name2
extern NSString * _Nonnull const Reason2;

@interface MYException: : NSException
@end
```

`MYException.m`

```
NSString * _Nonnull const Name1 = @"エラーの名前1";
NSString * _Nonnull const Reason1 = @"エラーの具体的な内容1";
NSString * _Nonnull const Name2 = @"エラー名前2";
NSString * _Nonnull const Reason2 = @"エラーの具体的な内容2";

@implement MYException
@end
```

コールバック先でエラーが発生した場合、そのエラーがわかった所で

```
@throw [MYExceptioon exceptionWithName:Name1 reason:Reason1 userInfo:nil];
```

の様な感じで例外を`throw`します。
`userInfo`はこの例では`nil`にしてなにも渡していませんが、`NSDictionary`オブジェクトを受け渡しする事でエラーコードや、エラーが起きたオブジェクトなど、より詳細な情報を受け渡す事ができます。

コールバック元は、例外を受け取れるように

```
@try {
    // この中でコールバック先を呼ぶ
    // （本来のエラーが起きなかったときのアルゴリズム）
}
@catch (MYException *exception) {
    // @throwされると、同じ型の処理を宣言したcatchに落ちてくる。
    // *exceptionを用いて例外処理
}
@catch (NSException *exception {
    // 型が違う例外もこの様にしてcatch出来る
    // @catch (型 *変数名) の型はNSExceptionを継承している必要はない
}
@finally {
    // 例外が起きても起きなくても例外発生後に行いたい処理
}
```

という記述をする必要がありますが、エラーがなければ`@try`の中を順次処理していき、あれば`@finally`の中が、そしてブロックの外に続いて処理が行われるので、本来のアルゴリズムとエラー処理を分離して書けるというメリットがあります。

Comment: Cocoa APIでは例外をcatchしてリカバリするような設計にはなっていません。例外を起こすのはすなわちバグか使い方の間違いを示します。よって例外をキャッチして復帰するというのが通常の使い方のAPIというのは、少なくともiOSプログラミングという文脈においては正しくありません。

Comment: 単純にNSErrorを返せば良いだけでしたね。ご指摘ありがとうございます

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ありません。目的・背景を質問文に追記しました。（Objective-Cにも例外機構があるのですね... 使おうと思ったことがなかったです）

Comment: 言い訳になってしまいますが、最近Swiftを主に使っていて、こちらではこういう使い方が推奨されているので、混同してしまいました。申し訳ありませんでした